# java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: java, ftp

I have a server running Apache FTPServer. The FTP server is functioning well until recently some upload from the client started to fail with this error that is attached. I have increased the MaxIdleTimeout but is still encountering this error. Anybody has any idea to what actually generated this error?

```
16 Mar 22:19:30,792 WARN [pool-3-thread-10] [LoggingFilter->log()]:122 - EXCEPTION :
java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.mina.transport.socket.nio.NioProcessor.read(NioProcessor.java:202)
    at org.apache.mina.transport.socket.nio.NioProcessor.read(NioProcessor.java:42)
    at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor.read(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:620)
    at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor.process(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:598)
    at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor.process(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:587)
    at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor.access$400(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:61)
    at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor$Processor.run(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:969)
    at org.apache.mina.util.NamePreservingRunnable.run(NamePreservingRunnable.java:64)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
16 Mar 22:19:30,792 WARN [pool-3-thread-10] [LoggingFilter->log()]:122 - EXCEPTION :
java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.mina.transport.socket.nio.NioProcessor.read(NioProcessor.java:202)
    at org.apache.mina.transport.socket.nio.NioProcessor.read(NioProcessor.java:42)
    at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor.read(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:620)
    at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor.process(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:598)
    at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor.process(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:587)
    at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor.access$400(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:61)
    at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor$Processor.run(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:969)
    at org.apache.mina.util.NamePreservingRunnable.run(NamePreservingRunnable.java:64)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
16 Mar 22:19:30,792 ERROR[pool-3-thread-10] [DefaultFtpHandler->exceptionCaught()]:156 - Exception caught, closing session
java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.mina.transport.socket.nio.NioProcessor.read(NioProcessor.java:202)
    at org.apache.mina.transport.socket.nio.NioProcessor.read(NioProcessor.java:42)
    at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor.read(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:620)
    at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor.process(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:598)
    at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor.process(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:587)
    at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor.access$400(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:61)
    at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor$Processor.run(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:969)
    at org.apache.mina.util.NamePreservingRunnable.run(NamePreservingRunnable.java:64)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
16 Mar 22:19:30,792 ERROR[pool-3-thread-10] [DefaultFtpHandler->exceptionCaught()]:156 - Exception caught, closing session
java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.mina.transport.socket.nio.NioProcessor.read(NioProcessor.java:202)
    at org.apache.mina.transport.socket.nio.NioProcessor.read(NioProcessor.java:42)
    at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor.read(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:620)
    at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor.process(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:598)
    at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor.process(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:587)
    at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor.access$400(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:61)
    at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor$Processor.run(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:969)
    at org.apache.mina.util.NamePreservingRunnable.run(NamePreservingRunnable.java:64)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like what the error says, the server closed your connection. Typically this is as a result of inactivity on your end. If you don't keep talking to the server it will close your connection. If the connections idle you need to send a stream of NOOP commands to it to let it know your still there.